# jQuery selector problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some tabs' info rendered with handlebars and here is my HTML:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabsId">
        <script id="tabs-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            {{#each Tabs}}
                <li data-tab-content={{Id}}><a href="#">{{Name}}</a></li>
            {{/each}}
        </script>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabsContentId">
    <script id="tabs-content-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each Tabs}}
            <div class="tab-content" data-tab-content="{{Id}}">{{Content}}</div>
        {{/each}}
    </script>
    </div>
```

And now I'm writing a function that will fill my future form when I double click on any tab. I've only managed how to get id and I don't understand how to get name and content values. I've tried to use jQuery `.text()` function, but I've failed. Here is my function:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabsId").on("dblclick", "li", function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data("tabContent");
        //var name = ?
        //var content = ?
        $('#inputIndex').val(id);
        //$('#inputTitle').val(name);
        //$('#textareaContent').val(content);       
    });
});
```

Comment: With templated code, you are better off providing the output HTML (e.g. as saved from your browser), so we do not have to mentally compile the moustache templates :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var id = $(this).data("tab-content");
var name = $(this).text();
// Get the content from the nth element in the other list (using the index of the LI clicked)
var content = $('#tabs-content-template .tab-content').eq($(this).index()).text();
```

Note: this only works as the same collection is used for both the LIs and the tab DIVs. Otherwise you will need to find it via the `data-tab-content` attribute.

Comment: note its `data-tab-content` and not `data-tabContent`

Comment: @Jamiec: `data()` does that translation :P but you *are* probably better of with `data('tab-content')` for readability :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).text()` then you can get the name in the dbclicked `li`.
Use `$('#tabsContentId div[data-tab-content="'  + id + '"]');` so you can get the target `div` which has an attribute `data-tab-content` and value is the `id` you previously retrieved.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#tabsId").on("dblclick", "li", function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data("tabContent");
        var name = $(this).text();
         alert("Name is :" + name);
         var targetDiv = $('div.tab-content[data-tab-content="'  + id + '"]');
         var content = targetDiv.text();
         alert("Content is :" +content);
        $('#inputIndex').val(id);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabsId">
           <li data-tab-content="t1"><a href="#">I'm Name</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabsContentId">
            <div class="tab-content" data-tab-content="t1">Here's content</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The `text()` of the `LI` will be the same as the `A`, so that part is a waste of time :)

Comment: For having the `data-tab-content` selector early on. +1

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly sure what you're after, but this would get the inner HTML of the first `<a>` element with *href="#"* inside the clicked element:

```
var name = $(this).find('a[href="#"]').first().html();
```